# How to access list of website users from SharePoint hosted app?

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-addin, user-accounts, aspx

My app is hosted here:

`https://mySite.sharepoint.com/sites/path/myApp/`

And user information is hosted here:

`https://mySite.sharepoint.com/sites/path/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx`

I already use this code to access lists outside of my app

```
    function getLists() {

        print("retrieving list");

        var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
        currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        hostcontext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentcontext, hostUrl);
        web = hostcontext.get_web(); // hostcontext instead of currentcontext

        listCollection = web.get_lists();
        list = listCollection.getByTitle(LIST_NAME);

        listItemCollection = list.getItems(""); // use CAML query for specific requests

        context.load(listItemCollection);
        context.executeQueryAsync(sharePointReady, queryFailed);
    }
```

How can I adjust this code to get a list of all the users in my website like their name and contact information? Or is there another method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### REST

```
/_api/Web/SiteUsers
```

#### JSOM

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var users = ctx.get_web().get_siteUsers();
ctx.load(users);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
  var userArray = [];
  var e = users.getEnumerator();
  while (e.moveNext()) {
    userArray.push(e.get_current());
  }
  console.log(userArray);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case `list = listCollection.getByTitle(LIST_NAME);` would become `list = listCollection.getByTitle("UserInformationList");` or `list = listCollection.getByTitle("User Information List");`.

That is the underlying list where the users are stored.

Comment: How about `/_api/Web/SiteUsers` or `context.get_web().get_siteUsers()`?

Comment: @PirateEric, I get an error that it doesn't exist. However, @eirikb, both of those seem to work. After using `get_siteUsers()` do you know how I can iterate over the `UserCollection` in JavaScript?

Comment: @crclayton `var userArray=[];var e = users.getEnumerator(); while(e.moveNext())userArray.push(e.get_current());`

Comment: Thanks a ton eirikb! If you want to leave an answer with that info I'll mark it right.